# How can I set Webmaster Tools to "Fetch as Google Bot" using SSL?

Tags: google-search-console, https

I have page which requires SSL so the page is https://.  I want to fetch this page as google bot inside of google webmasters' diagnostic tools however Google, from what I can tell, only allows http calls.  So when I put in my page all I get is a redirect from the http to the https page.

How can I fetch a page as google bot that is https?

Comment: This is a good and valid question but I notice you haven't mark your own answer as correct. In my opinion your own answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to add your domain a second time in the home page with the prefix of https.  So your domain will be registered twice, once with http://* and once with https://*.  You can then request the page from site with the https prefix.

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=7c6303361bcaeaf7&hl=en